# Perf dynamic tracing Failed to add events

Tags: java, linux, jvm, perf

I'm trying to learn how to use perf dynamic tracing on my java application running some JNI-based shared library written in C. The library is installed by path `/opt/myapp/lib/libmyapp.so` and then is run with the option `-Djava.library.path=/opt/myapp/lib/`. So I run the following command:

```
root@mypc:~# perf probe -x /opt/myapp/lib/libmyapp.so --add Java_net_my_app_pollEvents0
    Error: Failed to add events.
```

without any hint about the error cause. If there would be no global function with such a name in the library I would get the corresponding error description:

```
root@mypc:~# perf probe -x /opt/myapp/lib/libmyapp.so --add Java_net_my_app_pollEvents1234567
Probe point 'Java_net_my_app_pollEvents1234567' not found.
    Error: Failed to add events.
```

Can anyone give a hint how to fix this? I tried to add a probe for `malloc` function and it works just fine:

```
root@mypc:~# perf probe -x /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so --add malloc
Added new event:
  probe_libc:malloc    (on malloc in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so)

You can now use it in all perf tools, such as:

        perf record -e probe_libc:malloc -aR sleep 1
```

Comment: I haven't tried `perf probe` with JNI, but I may suggest [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/) instead. It can easily trace native functions capturing the mixed (native+Java) stack trace. Just try `profiler.sh -e Java_net_my_app_pollEvents0`

Comment: @apangin Not directly related to the question, but is it possible with async profiler to do sort of "zoom into shared object"? Or is there another way to inspect stack traces related to a particular so?

Comment: Not right now, but this is pretty easy to achieve with minimal changes. You may open a ticket in async-profiler if you'd like, and we'll discuss it there.

Comment: Had the same blank error now as I attempted to place a probe on a very long, mangled name.  I recalled `perf` might hide some errors unless you run it with `-v` (or possibly `perf --debug verbose=10`). I ran with `-v` and got a reasonable error now: `Error: Failed to add events. Reason: Argument list too long (Code: -7)`. I don't think that was the error in your case, but always run `perf` commands with `-v` if they don't work as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case the "argument list too long" error was because I was passing a very long mangled C++ symbol name to `perf probe`; explicitly naming the probe point with the `EVENT=` syntax allowed the probe point to be successfully added:

```
$ sudo perf probe -x myelf --no-demangle --add myalias=_SomeVeryLongMangledNameWhee
$ sudo perf record -e 'probe_myelf:myalias' -a -- sleep 30
```